# How to host a WCF service in another WCF service?

Tags: wcf, wcf-hosting

I have wcf service DLL , say WCFA. I have another wcf service dll , say WCFB which hosts wcfA.

Then, I have hosted WCFB using another consoleApp.

When I am tring to connect to WCFB using a client  ( inbuilt wcfclienttest client or my own test client ) , am getting wierd errors like

1. Error 404
2. FaultedException
3. Security exception etc....

So, am wodering if this scenario is ever possible using wcf?

Comment: Show some code snippets what you mean by hosting etc. Your question is totally unclear. Also show full exception message if you get any.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is certainly possible. Under the surface of the communication and serialization layer, a WCF application is just like any other application, and so therefore can call other WCF services if connectivity and other configuration permits.